# Bash script - sending email

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to send an email from a bash script but when I run the script it completes without any errors but the email doesn't seem to be sending (it doesn't arrive in my inbox at least)

```
SUBJECT="SET-EMAIL-SUBJECT"
EMAIL="me@address.co.uk"
EMAILMESSAGE="/home/me/workspace/ss/UI/UI/legacy/Output.txt"
echo "This is an email message test">$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "This is a second line">>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "This is a third line">>$EMAILMESSAGE
# send an email using /bin/mail
`/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE`
```

Thanks

Comment: And sending email by `mail` command manually works? Are you positively running a MTA, such as exim4, postfix or sendmail - and is it correctly configured?

Comment: Try to send mail to local user like `root` or your username. Then run the `mail` command as this user. This will allow you to check if local delivery works even if sending mail to the internet is not setup correctly. I've not tested it but your script looks okay.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, turns out we're not allowed to send mail from the server anymore as it resulted is us being black listed a couple of times, making this irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the limitation that what you're trying to do has been blocked, your error is the backticks on the last line of your script. `/bin/mail` is a command just like `echo`. What you're trying to do is to execute the mail command and then *execute the output* of the mail command.

Answer (score -1):

I created a function which I used in a script.  You may vary it as you wish.

```
send_mail(){
     printf "<what you want to say>  %s <what you want to say>  %d \n" <another function> <another function>| ${MAIL} -s "${SBJCT}" ${EMAIL}
}
```

Where:

```
MAIL=`which mail`
```